# Confusion about non-pure tensors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am beginning to read about tensor products and am slightly confused about the use of non-pure tensors. Precisely, let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M,N$ be $R$-modules.

In the construction of the tensor product, we obtain canonical bilinear map $$M\times N\xrightarrow{\otimes}M\otimes_R N,$$
via the mapping $(m,n)\mapsto m\otimes n$. I then know that via the universal property, for any bilinear map $B\colon M\times N\rightarrow P$, we can factor through the tensor product to obtain a linear map $L$ such that $B=L\circ\otimes_R$.

But it seems like the image of the canonical mapping $\otimes_R$ only maps to pure tensors (I feel like this could be wrong and I'm missing something obvious). So, every bilinear map, when we factor through the tensor product, only "goes through" the pure tensors, i.e., we are only taking values of $L$ which are evaluated at pure tensors. Is this understanding correct? It looks like then the non-pure tensors in the tensor product is extra material, but I think I'm missing the bigger picture.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but a bilinear map is, by bilinearity, defined by what it does to pure tensors. Without the non-pure tensors $M \otimes_R N$ wouldn't even be an abelian group!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Makes sense, thanks!